# Output filename with ts-loader do not rename the declaration files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have a server-only export that I name `index.server.ts`. I want this file to be renamed `server.js` so that `import foobar from "my-package/server` points to this file.

If I set an output filename in Webpack like this:

```json
{
   outuput: {
      filename: "server.js"
   }
}
```

The filename will be `server.js`, but the type declaration stays `index.server.d.ts`, therefore the import from other TypeScript packages fails, because TypeScript cannot find the right declaration file.

Any idea what's the expected behaviour/how to bypass this?

Comment: There's an option to set `types` in the the `package.json` with your typing file like this: `{"types": "./index.server.d.ts"}`

Comment: Yeah I finally figured it out, also it is to be noted that the next version of TypeScript (4.5) should have a correct support for package.json "exports", which is the best way to achieve what I want + also supports multiple entry points.